# How can I delete the contents a directory, without deleting the directory itself? Here's what I've tried so far

Tags: c#, directory

I'm making a button that reads a file path then deletes the files within the folder.  It's currently deleting the entire directory.  Here's my code:

```
public void deleteFiles(string Server)
{
    string output = "\\\\" + Server + "\\F\\Output";
    string input = "\\\\" + Server + "\\F\\Input";
    string exceptions = "\\\\" + Server + "\\F\\Exceptions";

    new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(input).Delete(true);
    new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(output).Delete(true);
    new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(exceptions).Delete(true);
}
```

Comment: [DirectoryInfo.Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.delete(v=vs.110).aspx) - Deletes a DirectoryInfo and its contents from a path. What is unclear here?

Comment: There will be unknown contents that passing into the listed file path.  The file path needs to remain in tact.  How do I delete the contents without deleting the path?

Comment: Okay, I've corrected my heading.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy: but it deletes content only with `true` as parameter, the overload without argument won't delete content, it will even raise an `IOException` if the directory isn't empty(same with `false` for recursive). So i assume that OP wants a recursive delete of files only-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would just deleting the directory and recreating it work? Or do you want to preserve permissions?

Comment: This will work.  I ended up setting it up this way since permissions were not an issue.  I was hoping there was a cleaner way for future reference.  There will be a time when I do need to preserve permissions.  Thanks for the help Agent Shark.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `Delete` method on `DirectoryInfo`, you should call it on `FileInfo's` instead:

```
var files =  new DirectoryInfo(input).GetFiles()
                .Concat(new DirectoryInfo(output).GetFiles())
                .Concat(new DirectoryInfo(exceptions).GetFiles());

foreach(var file in files)
     file.Delete();
```

Another way:

```
var files =  Directory.GetFiles(input)
                .Concat(Directory.GetFiles(output))
                .Concat(Directory.GetFiles(exceptions));

foreach(var file in files)
     File.Delete(file);
```

Comment: This also deletes the directory itself.

Answer (score 0):

`DirectoryInfo.Delete` and `Directory.Delete` delete empty directories, if you want to delete files you could try this method:

```
public void DeleteFiles(string path, bool recursive, string searchPattern = null)
{
    var entries = searchPattern == null ? Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(path) : Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(path, searchPattern);
    foreach(string entry in entries)
    {
        try
        {
            FileAttributes attr = File.GetAttributes(entry);
            //detect whether its a directory or file
            bool isDir = (attr & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory;
            if(!isDir)
                File.Delete(entry);
            else if(recursive)
                DeleteFiles(entry, true, searchPattern);
        }
        catch
        {
            //ignore
        }
    }
}
```